# Add class on horizontal scroll with the scroll class add to the box

Tags: wordpress

I want to add class on horizontal scroll with the scroll a class add to the box like in the image with the sroll a class added then i add image on the class and also remove class when scroll back.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/As29S.png]

I tried to add class but i can't.

Comment: No idea what you mean by "adding a class". Also have no idea what toolkit you are using.

Comment: Is the posted example  a webpage or a gui?

Comment: I am using wordpress platform with elementor page builder

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Comment: And where is the connection to Java?